# Chain Max and Where in Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Given this code:

```
Book[] books = new Book[3]
    {
        new Book("100", "Title1"),
        new Book("200", "Title2"),
        new Book("200", "Title3"),
    };

getBookWithMostPages() {
    var max = books.Max(book => book.pages);
    return books.FirstOrDefault((book) => book.pages == max);
}
```

Is it possible (there is any documented way) to chain Max and FirstOrDefault and return the same result ?

Answer (score 4):

.NET 6 introduced the [MaxBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.maxby?view=net-6.0) operator. I think that might be what you're looking for:

```
var book = books.MaxBy(b => b.Pages);
```

Here's the implementation [in the reference source](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/Max.cs,4a040b1501b32d51) so if you're using the older version of .NET you should be able to just copy it into your codebase. If of course that's what you want...

Comment: Is there also a way in older .NET versions ?

Comment: @ClaudioFerraro not a built-in way as far as I know.

Comment: @ClaudioFerraro There's a `MaxBy` NuGet package you could install - it's very small: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MoreLinq.Source.MoreEnumerable.MaxBy/

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the array and return the first value:

```
return books.OrderByDescending(book => book.pages)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```